# JavaScript does not redirect on true statement

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

```
<label>Username:</label>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text" value="wawa">
<label>Password:</label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" value="123456">
<input value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick='loginme();'>

function loginme () {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var params = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var url = "login.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function () {                            
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'checking...';
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
        success: function (html) {  
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = html; // the code only executes until here

            if(red == "OK") { 
               window.location = 'account.php'; //it does not execute here i think.
               alert(html); // even here.
           }                                     
        }
    }
```

Hi I know, this question was asked many times. but there are no exact answers. So here I am with this same question. It will not redirect me to accounts page. The same with the others, I also tried redirection alone, and it works, but not in the actual code. Its been four years of coding ajax but this is the first time I have encountered this problem. I don't know what's going on with the code. Even when I start everything from scratch, it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: where is `red` declared at?

Comment: This isn't even valid javascript.  You don't ever close your parentheses in the ajax call.

Comment: You don't have a semicolon after the AJAX call. Also, you do not have a bracket to close the function.

Comment: I think its working now, instead of a string message from php indicating a success, I change it to an integer 1, and it works. byt he way 'if(red=="OK"){ ' is if(html=="OK"){, i forgot to change. ^_^

Comment: and it does not work with the <form></form> tag. If somebody got a fix for this, please post it for our fellow SO'ers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loginme() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var params = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var url = "login.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function () {                            
            // document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'checking...';
        },
        complete: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) {              
            if(response == "OK") { 
               window.location.href = 'account.php'; //it does not execute here i think.
               alert(html); // even here.
           }                                     
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<label>Username:</label>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text" value="wawa">
<label>Password:</label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" value="123456">
<input value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick='loginme();'>


</body>
</html>
```

Inside login.php, if evrything goes fine write `echo "OK";exit;` then your page will redirect to account.php

Hope this will help!

Comment: Can you explain what i am missing!? IDK what is the difference with your answer, but its working with or without the " exit; " inside logpin.php. thanks. I will post the running code bellow.

Comment: It is upto you whether to use string or numeric values, does not make any difference till the point you are writing nice code. exit; makes the stop and return back, for safer side i have used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loginme() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var params = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var url = "login1.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function () {                            
             document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'checking...';
        },
        complete: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) {        
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response;
            if(response == "OK") { 
               window.location.href = 'account.php'; //it does not execute here i think.
               //alert(html); // even here.
           }                                     
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<label>Username:</label>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text" value="wawa">
<label>Password:</label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" value="123456">
<input value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick='loginme();'>
<div id='status'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Still not working with the `<form>` tag. but i got my old code running not using the `echo="OK"` response but with boolean `1 or 0`, so i am using intiger 1 instead of a string 'OK'.

Comment: This problem is solved. PS. If the 'if statement' does not recognize the returned string, use boolean.